# initialValues for multiple select in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have select element defined as multiple. I want to pass initialValues to redux-form

```
     <Field 
          name="favoriteColor" 
          component="select"
          type="select-multiple"
          multiple >
            <option value="">Select a color...</option>
            {colors.map(colorOption => (
              <option value={colorOption.name} key={colorOption.name}>
                {colorOption.name}
              </option>
            ))}
      </Field>
```

[CodeSandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/7w0kp2l1q0)

Redux-form reacts to changes like favoriteColor: ['Blue', 'Green', ...], but i need favoriteColor: [{name: 'Blue'}, {name: 'Green'}, ...]. Also for initializing it has to be watch to name field of object

Comment: You want to pass intialValues to redux-form ?

Comment: Not actually. My initialValues looks like [ { name: 'Blue' }, { name: 'Yellow' } ], so I want show which options selected, also send with same structure to BE

Answer (score 0):

Use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to manipute data on your `initialValues` prop of your form.

https://codesandbox.io/s/318n0oy6xp

Comment: I can do it with .map(item => item.name) too. That's not right. Because when I will send data to BE, I will need to do same thing the opposite. I am looking for redux-form standard way